# Numbers from a string into a list java

Tags: java, json, string, integer, contains

So I request some data from an API using a http post method and then I receive a JSON response and then I have a string that looks like the JSON response, something like this:

```
{"status": "OK", "results": [{"score": 0.0, "id": "2"}, {"score": 1.0, "id": "3"}, {"score": 0.0, "id": "0"}, {"score": 0.0, "id": "1"}, {"score": 0.0, "id": "6"}, {"score": 0.23606, "id": "7"}, {"score": 0.0, "id": "4"}, {"score": -0.2295, "id": "5"}, {"score": 0.41086, "id": "8"}, {"score": 0.39129, "id": "9"}]}
```

I want to extract the numbers from this list or better yet check how many numbers are between 0.2-1.0 and if this condition is true increment a integer value I have.

for instance i want to do something like this but I just cannot find the right syntax for me.

```
    if(responseString.contains("0.0-0.2")
    {
    OccurencesNeutral++
    }
    if(responseString.contains("0.2-1.0")
    {
    OccurencesPositive++
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with JSON, you should use the [JSONObject API](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html). In your case, something like this should work:

```
try {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(theStringYouGot);
    JSONArray results = json.getJSONArray("results");
    for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject data = results.getJSONObject(i);
        double score = data.getDouble("score");
    }
} catch (JSONException x) {
    // Handle exception...
}
```

In your code, you should probably replace the hardcoded field names with constants for clean code.

Comment: hey chris this seems like exactly what i'm looking for but i'm getting an error with the line JSONObject data = results1.get(i); I'm quite new to JSON hence why I changed the responsebody to a string straight away

Comment: I updated my answer, does it work now? I just wrote it from my mind, so it might have had the stray syntax error...

Comment: It is now working with the line results1.get(i) but it would seem it does not like the data.get("score") being declared as a double?

Comment: If i cast it to a double it then gives me the error that a JSONArray cannot be converted to a JSONObject

Comment: Ok, sorry, needed to use `getDouble` instead of just `get`. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Json libraray, there will methods to serialize and create an Object from the string, so you can search the number in the new object with the correct get method.

For example in the org.json you can do

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject("your string");
```

Answer (score 0):

Code in groovy to do so (change 0.2 to args)

```
def JsonSlurper js = new JsonSlurper()
def o = js.parseText(jsonStr)
def (neu, pos) = [0, 0]
o.results.each {
    if (it.score <= 0.2) neu ++
    else pos ++
}
println "$neu $pos"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want regex try this,

```
    int OccurencesNeutral=0;
    int OccurencesPositive=0;
    String regex="((-?\\d+)\\.(\\d+))";
    String str="{\"status\": \"OK\", \"results\": [{\"score\": 0.0, \"id\": \"2\"}, {\"score\": 1.0, \"id\": \"3\"}, {\"score\": 0.0, \"id\": \"0\"}, {\"score\": 0.0, \"id\": \"1\"}, {\"score\": 0.0, \"id\": \"6\"}, {\"score\": 0.23606, \"id\": \"7\"}, {\"score\": 0.0, \"id\": \"4\"}, {\"score\": -0.2295, \"id\": \"5\"}, {\"score\": 0.41086, \"id\": \"8\"}, {\"score\": 0.39129, \"id\": \"9\"}]}";

    Pattern p=Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m=p.matcher(str);

    float f=0;
    while(m.find()){
        f=Float.parseFloat(m.group());
        if(f>0 && f<0.2)
            OccurencesNeutral++;
        if(f>0.2 && f<1.0)
            OccurencesPositive++;
    }

    System.out.println("Neutral="+OccurencesNeutral+"\t"+"Positives="+OccurencesPositive);
```

Comment: Hey RKC thanks for your reply, this seems to be working for the most part however if the score is say for instance -0.23553 it will still be added to occurrencesPositive, does this regex work for negative numbers i tried adding if(f<0.0){occurrencesNeg++} but to no avail

Comment: Modified my regex above.Now it will work for negative numbers also.

Comment: Brillance! Works perfectly thanks very much, just to aid my understanding it is searching the string, then looking for the pattern of a digit(can now be minus) . then another digit correct? then when this is found we use the matcher to allocate what type we want i.e pos,neg or neu

Comment: Go through this for a clear understanding on regex patterns.http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html